# series functions of complex variable $ z $ and alternating zeta function convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n(z)$ and $p_n(z)$ two series  functions of complex variable $z$ defined as the

following:

$f_n(z)$=$ \sum_{n}exp({(-1)}^{n-1}{n^{-z}}))  $

$p_n(z)$=$exp(\sum_{n}({(-1)}^{n-1}{n^{-z}})$

let $z=\alpha+i\beta$  and  $0<Re(z)<1$ .

My question is : does $f_n(z)$= $p_n(z)$  for $0<Re(z)<1$ and $\beta >0$?

if it does , how i can show that ?

I would be interest for any comments or any replies

Comment: Neither of those series converge for $0 < \operatorname{Re}(z) < 1$.

Comment: OK but i want a prove for this , see my question is equivalent to

Comment: i see that :$p_n(z)=1$ ,for $0<Re(z)<1$ , and for some $\beta >0$ , $n$  go to infinity

Comment: see , i edited my data